# Using problemMatcher with vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup a problemMatcher for a build task inside VSCode, the command generate messages like the following:

```
14 : ../../Dsrc/path/to/file.h:44:58: error: class ‘tf::ARandomClass’ does not have any field named ‘epsilon’
```

Using https://regex101.com/ I constructed a the following expression to build the problem matcher: `\.\.\/\.\.\/Dsrc\/(.*?):(.*?):(.*?): (.*?): (.*?)$`

However, the following problem matcher inside VS Code does not work:

```
  "problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "cpp",
    "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
    "pattern": {
      "regexp": "\.\.\/\.\.\/Dsrc\/(.*?):(.*?):(.*?): (.*?): (.*?)$",
      "file": 1,
      "line": 2,
      "column": 3,
      "severity": 4,
      "message": 5
    }
  },
```

Even if I remove the `\.\.\/\.\.\/Dsrc\/` part, it does seems do match anything inside the terminal. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

try the regex:

```
^\d+\s*:\s*([^:]+):(\d+):(\d+): (.*?): (.*?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the configuration file is JSON, you need to escape your escapes in the `regexp` value (i.e., double up your backslashes):

```
      "regexp": "\\.\\.\\/\\.\\.\\/Dsrc\\/(.*?):(.*?):(.*?): (.*?): (.*?)$",
```